MS Teams bot using Botframework SDK v4 has severe lag
I run a MS Teams bot on a VM written in Python Botframework SDK v4. The VM is connected to MS Teams using ngrok, coupled with some other rules that we’ve put it to harden the security of the network tunnel.
There is always a 4-7 second lag for user messages to reach the VM. On the other hand, the response from VM to the user is usually instantaneous.
Is this lag expected? If not, how can I eliminate the lag? I’ve been experiencing the lag since launching the bot about 2 years ago.
Thank you.
Note: I am posting this question here as botframework’s GitHub suggested (“how does it work”). I don’t have code that can reproduce this issue, as it seems to be a networking issue than coding issue.

Maybe you need to use something like, and we are allowed to suggest brands but similar to a wire fish ... but you perhaps need a tracing software to figure out the pathing to see where the bottleneck is happening?

@easleyfixed i don’t have a suitable tracing software. But ngrok’s traffic monitoring shows no discernible lag at ngrok (only few ms of lag). I’m wondering if there are settings in azure admin or the bot’s settings that could improve the performance.

Without posting the settings for someone to see, they won't be able to offer suggestings for changes, so if you can update the question with that, perhaps someone can offer some advice.  Its still possible it could use some more resources, despite it not appearing to need them.  And if its not on the calculations, then its the traffic somehow.

Investigate any network latency issues between the VM and MS Teams. This could involve checking the network path, any firewalls, or other security appliances that might be introducing delays. Make sure you're using the latest version of the Python Botframework SDK v4 and that all dependencies are up to date.

@Prasad-MSFT are there any settings on the admin portal, such as choosing the region etc? We ask this because the bot responding with nearly no lag, momentarily, during the 19th of July “event”.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/set-preferences#language--region
